# What generates a neutron star's magnetic field?

Tags: electromagnetism, magnetic-fields, angular-momentum, magnetic-moment, neutron-stars

Is the magnetic field of a neutron star generated by the minuscule amount of protons and electrons left or the spin of the neutrons?
If its because of the spin of the neutrons, how come they are all lined up?

Comment: But why neutrons can cause magnetism if they are not charged ?